# Script R invoked by Task Scheduler with no popup and variable run time

Tags: r

I run the code periodically (every 15 minutes) using Task Scheduler (Windows)- the *.bat file is called by a task in the Task Scheduler.

Unfortunately, the pop-up console window makes your work very difficult. I spent a lot of time looking for a way to run the script in the background without the pop-up window and I couldn't find a solution.

The second thing - is it possible to set a new script launch schedule from the R level depending on the result obtained during the last run? I expect this will require changes to the Windows registry.